# SharePoint 2010 SP1 upgrade fails

Tags: 2010, service-pack, patching

I have installed SP1 for SharePoint 2010. After installation I am running PSCONFIG to complete the installation. It fails with this error message:

```
Unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain.
```

According to some blogs this can be fixed by giving the executing user access to a specific AD container 'Microsoft SharePoint Products'.

Now to the question: I do not have any access to the AD at all. Is there a way to complete the SP1 installation without having access to that AD container?

**Update:**
I have talked to the AD guys and it seems that no one changed anything wrt. the System container with the recent year. There is no 'Microsoft SharePoint Products' container under the 'System' container. So it seems that the AD tracking function is being introduced with SP1 (please correct me if I am wrong). Also there is little hope to get 'Create Service Connection Point objects' rights on the required AD container which leaves me with a partially patched system.

Comment: Some blogs have suggested that they got this fixed by simply restarting the SharePoint Timer service. I am not sure how this fixes the issue, but did you give that a try?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I restarted SPTimerV4 but it's still the same error...

Answer (score 1):

Your AD is configured to track SharePoint installations. All accounts that are used to run PSCONFIG need to have specific permission on a specific AD container in order to be able to add a marker of itself to the container.

Probably the tracking was enabled after initial SharePoint installation, or are you perhaps using different account from the original setup account that might still have permissions in the AD container?

But, if it is the correct and same account, you do need to get a hold of some AD person.

[More here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730261.aspx)

Comment: I am definetly running with the same account as when installing SharePoint. During the installation half a year ago I did not have any issues...